# Docker container not connecting to https endpoints

Tags: ssl, networking, https, docker, openstack

From inside a docker container, I'm running

```
# openssl s_client -connect rubygems.org:443 -state -nbio 2>&1 | grep "^SSL"     

SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

That's all I get

I can't connect to any https site from within the docker container. The container is running on an openstack vm. The vm can connect via https.

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

```
root@ce239554761d:/# curl -vv https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 216.58.217.46...
* Connected to google.com (216.58.217.46) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

and then it hangs.

Also, I'm getting intermittent successes now.

*Sanity Checks:*

- changing the docker ips doesn't fix the problem
- The docker containers work on my local machine
- The docker containers work on other clouds
- Docker 1.10.0 doesn't work in the vms
- Docker 1.9.1 works in the vms

Comment: related: http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/20530-ssl-issues-with-bundlerrubygemsorg-bundle-install-from-inside-of-a-docker-container

Comment: If you parse through the related link above, something is missing from your docker distro.   ca-certificates maybe?

Comment: @Eli This is not a rubygems-specific problem. None of my containers can access any https sites.

@user2105103, I have ca-certificates installed, `apt-get update` hangs

Comment: If `apt-get update` hangs, then it could be an issue with the MTU on docker host. Try setting the MTU to lower value.

Comment: We're experiencing the same problems and it appears to be a tricky bug in OpenStack. I filed a bug there: https://bugs.launchpad.net/neutron/+bug/1595762

Answer (score 11):

I was given a solution by the [Docker community](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20178#issuecomment-228531711)

OpenStack network seems to use lower MTU values and Docker does not infer the MTU settings from the host's network card [since 1.10](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22028).

To run docker daemon with custom MTU settings, you can follow [this blog post](https://rahulait.wordpress.com/2016/02/28/modifying-default-mtu-for-docker-containers/), that says:

```
$ cp /lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Edit a line in the new file to look like this:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --mtu=1454
```

Or (as suggested below by Dionysius), create and edit the file
`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/fixmtu.conf` as follow:

```
[Service]
# Reset ExecStart & update mtu (see original command in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service)
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --mtu=1454.
```

MTU of 1454 is the value that seems to be common with OpenStack. You can look it up in your host using ifconfig.

Finally restart Docker:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Comment: Instead of copying the whole unit file (which could possible be changed by the package author) consider only updating that one line using: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/fixmtu.conf file with the contents:
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --mtu=1454. Don't forget to systemctl daemon-reload and restart docker